# React router v6 2elements with the same url path '/'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to have 2elements Dashboard and Login with the same url path ('/') but in two separated outlets when the user is logged in, i want to render the Dashboard and when is not render the Login page

```
import { lazy, Suspense, useMemo } from 'react'
import {
  Route,
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Navigate,
  Outlet,
} from 'react-router-dom'
import * as PATHS from './constants/routes'
import UserContext from './context/user'
import useAuthListener from './hooks/use-auth-listener'

const Login = lazy(() => import('./pages/Login'))
const Register = lazy(() => import('./pages/Register'))
const NotFound = lazy(() => import('./pages/NotFound'))
const Dashboard = lazy(() => import('./pages/Dashboard'))

const PrivateOutlet = () => {
  const { user } = useAuthListener()
  return user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to={PATHS.LOGIN} />
}
const PublicOutlet = () => {
  const { user } = useAuthListener()
  return !user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to={PATHS.DASHBOARD} />
}
const App = () => {
  const { user } = useAuthListener()
  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({
      user,
    }),
    [{ user }]
  )

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route element={<PublicOutlet />}>
              <Route path={PATHS.LOGIN} element={<Login />} />
              <Route path={PATHS.SIGNUP} element={<Register />} />
            </Route>
            <Route element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
              <Route path={PATHS.NOTFOUND} element={<NotFound />} />
              <Route path={PATHS.DASHBOARD} element={<Dashboard />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Suspense>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default App
```

I already have a workaround of removing the PublicOutlet and adding a

```
 <Route path={PATHS.LOGIN} element={!user ? <Login />} :<Dashboard />
```

but i would like to check if there is a better way of doing it in the PublicOutlet am using react router V6

Comment: Where is any route on path `"/"` being rendered? It seems the `PublicOutlet` and `PrivateOutlet` components already handle redirecting authenticated/unauthenticated users to the correct path. What is the `PATHS.LOGIN` Where are you wanting to add this additional route?

Comment: the thing is both PATHS.LOGIN and PATHS.DASHBOARD go the same path '/' , am expecting to render the component needed depending on the authentication

Comment: I see, then a single route `<Route path={PATHS.LOGIN} element={!user ? <Login /> : <Dashboard />} />` will be sufficient.

Comment: Do you basically want `"/"` to be a protected route and render the `Dashboard` component? It's pretty common to render the `Login` component on its own route, i.e. `"/login"`.

Comment: @DrewReese yes the workaround works its that am looking if there is a better way (inside the protection functions)

Comment: and yes rendering the login component on its own route would be the common practice but not all the time (example : Instagram)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for then. I don't think there's any "better way". You can either render a single route that renders one or the other of `Login` and `Dashboard` directly based on `user`, or you can render them independently on the same path so long as they are mutually exclusive like they are with your protected route components. Is there an issue with the current implementation?

Comment: lol, no actually it works smoothly as I already stated, would preferred if there is a way this can be managed from the functions so i dont use the conditional rendering in the route ^^' Thanks

Comment: Well, the code isn't conditionally rendering `Route` components, which is good IMO, and you are only *possibly* conditionally rendering the routed component, i.e. the `element` prop, depending on which implementation is used.